# VBA to get a specific string from a multiline string

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below string that is being read from a notepad from a drive. While vba reading the below string, I would like to get the NeedID(abc123) to store it in a variable. Sometime i'll have the below information repeated multiple times with different "NeedID"s and I need the "Need ID" saved in an array to call them later.

```
NeedID = abc123    NAME       = Someone, Nameenter code here
TYPE       = moon
as  = Dept      us =   xyz
Acdi  = 96633   DENt   = Test DET
```

Below code reads the above file from a drive

```
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\\FileID.txt")
txtfileID = oFS.ReadAllenter
```

Any idea to get the needid please.

Comment: Try a [regular expression](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=vba+regexp).

Comment: Use a RegEx for ultimate in powerful string parsing.  For more pedestrian code (ideal for beginners) use VBA.Split to break out tokens.